# How to filter an array inside an object based on user input?

Tags: javascript

Assume this object:

```
const data = {
    "text-a": ["Text-1", "Text-2", "Example-3", "Text-4"],
    "text-b": ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Other-Example-3", "Text-1b"]
}

// This object should be updated only with the data that matches the searchInput. 
var filteredData = {} 

// This value changes on user text input.
var searchInput = "tex"
```

and need to filter it based on user text input. The filter should be applied to the array values, and when no values match the search input, remove its key as well.

my current non-working implementation looks like this, but I cannot get it working as it returns always 'undefined:

```
filteredData = Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => (
    filteredData[key] = data[key].filter((x) => 
   (x.includes(searchInput)))
))
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.forEach()` method [returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) in JavaScript, so assigning the result of that to `filteredData` is going to make `filteredData` undefined.

One way to approach this is to get the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of your `data` object (`[[key, value], [key2, value2], ...]` and then map each of the inner entry arrays (using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to new entries, where each value is a filtered version of your array. Once you've transformed each inner entry array by mapping it, you can perform an additional filter to keep only the key-value pairs where your array's value length is more than `0` (non-empty). You can then convert the transformed array of entries into a new object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const data = {
    "text-a": ["Text-1", "Text-2", "Example-3", "Text-4"],
    "text-b": ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Other-Example-3", "Text-1b"]
};

const searchInput = "tex";
const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  value.filter(val => val.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()))
]).filter(([, val]) => val.length > 0));

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: It works great, thank you also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Three remarks about your code:

- The way you use `includes` performs a case-sensitive search, my suggestion uses a case-insensitive regular expression.
- The `filteredData` you construct is an array, but you seem to want an object.
- You need a check whether an array becomes empty after filtering.

```js
const data = {
  "text-a": ["Text-1", "Text-2", "Example-3", "Text-4"],
  "text-b": ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Other-Example-3", "Text-1b"]
};
const filteredData = {};
var searchInput = new RegExp("tex", "i"); // case-insensitive
for (var p in data) {
  var filtered = data[p].filter(text => searchInput.test(text));
  if (filtered.length > 0) filteredData[p] = filtered;
}
console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: One thing about using a regular expression in this case is that since `"tex"` comes from user input there might be unintended behavior if the user were to enter a regular expression character (eg: `.`) into their input. Unfortunately, JS doesn't have a good way to escape regex easily (at least [not yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regex-escaping)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const data = {
    "text-a": ["Text-1", "Text-2", "Example-3", "Text-4"],
    "text-b": ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Other-Example-3", "Text-1b"]
};

var searchInput = "Tex";

var filteredData = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const filteredArray = data[key].filter(x => x.includes(searchInput));
    if (filteredArray.length > 0) {
        acc[key] = filteredArray;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

// Convert filteredData to text representation
var filteredDataText = Object.keys(filteredData).map(key => {
    return `${key}: ${filteredData[key].join(', ')}`;
}).join('\n');

console.log(filteredDataText);
```

and if you want make case insensitive:

```
const data = {
    "text-a": ["Text-1", "Text-2", "Example-3", "Text-4"],
    "text-b": ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Other-Example-3", "Text-1b"]
};

var searchInput = "Tex";

var filteredData = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const filteredArray = data[key].filter(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()));
    if (filteredArray.length > 0) {
        acc[key] = filteredArray;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

// Convert filteredData to text representation
var filteredDataText = Object.keys(filteredData).map(key => {
    return `${key}: ${filteredData[key].join(', ')}`;
}).join('\n');

console.log(filteredDataText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// This value changes on user text input.
const searchInput = "tex";

const data = {
    "text-a": ["Text-1", "Text-2", "Example-3", "Text-4"],
    "text-b": ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Other-Example-3", "Text-1b"],
    "": ["teX", "Xet", "ext", "T E X", "teks"],
    empty: [],
    2: ["tëxt"], // no locale support
    five: Array(5).fill(searchInput), // this will be duplicated, not "reduced"
    //'not an array': 'this would eventually fail'
};

const searched = searchInput.toLowerCase(); 
// using RegExp case-insensitive search would need to escape the user input string, e.g. https://lodash.com/docs#escapeRegExp

// This object should be updated only with the data that matches the searchInput. 
const filteredData = {};

for(const key of Object.keys(data)) {
  const foundTexts = data[key].filter(text => text.toLowerCase().includes(searched));
  if (foundTexts.length > 0) filteredData[key] = foundTexts;
}

console.log(filteredData);
```